# PHP Ranking Products

Tags: php, sorting, ranking, rating, product

I want to sort my products based on three criteria

1. Rating(5 star)
2. Comments
3. Weight of User favorite entry for this product

Does anyone know the better way to rank my product based on this three criteria ?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort using a whole range of interesting criteria:

- Most popular (i.e. those with the highest sales figure)
- Most viewed (those with the highest viewcount)
- Editor's favourites (ones which you manually select)
- Most recent

etc.

Comment: Its a online product cateloge not shopping cart.I want to sort this considering above mentione three criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be good practise. Maybe you can also rank by search engine reference (visitors refers from search enginge)

Comment: Hai yes but serach engine don't know about my comment and favorite weight.That's why i think about my own algorithm.

Comment: It seems like i do not really understand what is your question. Can you extend/clarify your question?

Comment: yes my product cateloge system hold tree dynamic features which user can rate ,commnet and add to their favorite list. I am looking for an algorithm to sort based on this tree critiria.Total rank weight of each product should be a sum up of rating weight + comment weight +favorite list weight

Comment: It seems like you give an answer to yourself? "Total rank weight of each product should be a sum up of rating weight + comment weight +favorite list weight." Maybe you can give different weight on the different type. So maybe rating rank counts double, favorite ranks  tripple and comments counts single?

Comment: yes but i am looking for equations which give me the accurate weight for each item.

Comment: Not sure if i understand you right... i think we need your datamodel to give you an accurate answer.